# Android Paging Library V3 can't handle return type

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

I'm using Paging Library v3 and I'm getting this error when trying to use the RxRemoteMediator

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
(androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Integer, MyClass>).
```

Here's the code

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM item_table LIMIT 20")
fun loadAllItems(): PagingSource<Int, MyClass>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668605/paging-compile-issue-not-sure-how-to-convert-a-cursor-to-this-methods-return

Comment: Thanks! Once I updated the room version from `2.2.5` to `2.3.0-alpha02` it worked!